# How to make backwards-compatible 360 games see Xbox One storage?

Tags: xbox-one, backwards-compatibility

When I e.g. start Mass Effect (a backwards-compatible 360 game) on my Xbox One, it asks me what storage device I want to store saves on, but only gives me the option of using cloud storage. I don't want to do this, both because my Internet is spotty and because I'm letting my XBL Gold lapse at the end of the month. **How can I make these 360 games see local storage on my Xbox One?**

It would be OK if they could use a flash drive I plug into a USB port (though this solution is sub-optimal since I usually have three controllers plugged in), but I don't have a spare flash drive and don't want to buy one when I don't know if it will work.

It would be more ideal, then, if I could get 360 game data saving working with my XB1's internal storage, but OK if I can do it with a flash drive. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Virtual Xbox360 is not able to use any external storage devices connected to the XboxOne.

As outlined in the Xbox One Backwards compatibility FAQ, the Xbox360 shares saves with the Xbox one via cloud storage. This is because it's the storage the 360 has access to.

[**How do I pick up at the same place in a game on Xbox One where I left off on Xbox 360?**](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq#8f12864746df4ba49f79d06fa08fa5e4)

Comment: I'm not asking how to share saves. I want to create new ones on a local hard drive.

Comment: @zpletan The 'Virtual' Xbox360 can only access storage via the cloud - no access to external storage devices unfortunately.

Comment: @zpletan Answer updated to address your question better.

Comment: OK, thanks. I don't see there where it says XB1 can *only* use the cloud, though. Is this from experience you're talking? (Which is fine, BTW, I just would like to know.)

Comment: From experience, yes. Just thought I'd back it up with the XB1 FAQ as I figured if it was possible it would have been provided as an option to transfer saves also.

Comment: Excellent, I getcha now. One last question before I mark this as the answer: have you tried with an external drive?

Comment: Yeah, I've got an external hard drive hooked up to my XB1 as I've only got the 500GB version of the console. It's doesn't show up as a device on the 360.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the games (or career if you are playing Mass Effect) just like you would on the Xbox 360

Comment: Yes, except there's only the option to save to "Xbox 360 Cloud Storage" or whatever it's called. No option to save to my internal HD, and I don't have an external to test.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem, go to your settings on your Xbox One, then click all settings. Make your way to `System` > `Storage` and from there click on `Clear local Xbox 360 storage`. Your Xbox One will reset and once you open the game it should sign you in to your account automatically (it did for me at least, but I did this with Dragon Age: Origins).

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a Wifi connection? When loading an Xbox 360 game for backwards compatibility you just have to insert the game (e.g. Mass Effect) into the Xbox One and it will automatically start to install, and will prompt you to update the software.

When it asks you if you want the update press 'Update Now. It should take about 10 to 20 minutes. Select internal storage (if you have the space).

I just updated mine last week and it worked fine.

Comment: Could have been a little clearer—I'm asking for help with saves, not installs. I already have it downloaded to my XB1 (internal storage).